# Why load balance between multiple instances of an application on a single server?

Tags: python, nginx, pylons, pyramid

I am working with Pyramid, and when it comes to deploying, I came across this [tutorial](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/deployment.html).

What is the point of running multiple instances of the same app on the same server?
Is there an optimal amount of instances I should run?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite common these days for a system to have more than one core, IE, processor. If you want to take full advantage of it, you should run as many instances as there are processors, or one less for the OS. This will allow you to take the maximum advantage of the system.

It is also possible, if your code has considerable IO calls, that the optimal value is even higher than the number of cores, as while one thread is getting data from, say, the HD, another can be running on the processor.

Comment: Actually, more than that is typically safe and can even be optimal.  It's also about how much time processes spend waiting on stuff like I/O.  If they're blocking a lot, another process could be running and taking advantage of that unused CPU time.

Comment: @cHao: Hmmm, good point, guess I'm just not used to waiting for IO commands... Will edit to add the info in.

Comment: And python does not have true multi-threading. But it is handled through thread-pooled workers : a worker process may handle several requests at a time with different threads as opposed to prefork model: a process may handle only one request, otherwise it reports as idle. So its a good idea to have 1+ instances.

Comment: what would you guys say is the optimal amount of instances then? 2 per core?

Comment: @Jonathan: There's no set-in-stone number.  That's part of why we make the big bucks.  :)  The optimal number depends entirely on your app and your server's performance.  You have to balance disk I/O, network I/O, and CPU (and some other stuff, like OS resources / memory) when deciding what's better.